# NPM vendored plugin fails to build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I'm getting the following really weird build issues that I can't seem to track down against a gatsby plugin I'm building: https://github.com/flockcover/gatsby-plugin-branch-web-sdk. Oddly enough, when I had the exact same plugin under a plugins directory, rather than vendored through npm, the build passed just fine

````
141 | var REACT_CONTEXT_TYPE = hasSymbol ? Symbol.for('react.context') : 0xeace;
  142 | var REACT_ASYNC_MODE_TYPE = hasSymbol ? Symbol.for('react.async_mode') : 0xeacf;
> 143 | var REACT_FORWARD_REF_TYPE = hasSymbol ? Symbol.for('react.forward_ref') : 0xead0;
      | ^
  144 | 
  145 | // A reserved attribute.
  146 | // It is handled by React separately and shouldn't be written to the DOM.


  WebpackError: 

  - react-dom-server.node.development.js?5336:143 Parser.pp$4.raise
    ~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js?5336:143:1

  - react.development.js?1871:438 Parser.pp.unexpected
    ~/react/cjs/react.development.js?1871:438:1

  - emptyObject.js?42e4:11 Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom
    ~/fbjs/lib/emptyObject.js?42e4:11:1

  - index.js?2927:58 Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts
    ~/object-assign/index.js?2927:58:1



  - react.development.js?1871:1455 Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional
    ~/react/cjs/react.development.js?1871:1455:1

  - react.development.js?1871:1432 Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign
    ~/react/cjs/react.development.js?1871:1432:1


  - invariant.js?4599:48 Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom
    ~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js?4599:48:27

  - index.js?2927:58 Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts
    ~/object-assign/index.js?2927:58:1



  - react.development.js?1871:1455 Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional
    ~/react/cjs/react.development.js?1871:1455:1

  - react.development.js?1871:1432 Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign
    ~/react/cjs/react.development.js?1871:1432:1
```

gatsby clipboard:
```
 System:
    OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
    CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 8.9.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.2/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.9.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 5.5.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.2/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 69.0.3497.100
    Firefox: 61.0.2
    Safari: 11.1
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: 1.9.273 => 1.9.273 
    gatsby-link: ^1.6.40 => 1.6.46 
    gatsby-plugin-emotion: ^1.1.17 => 1.1.17 
    gatsby-plugin-intercom-spa: ^0.0.5 => 0.0.5 
    gatsby-plugin-netlify: ^1.0.19 => 1.0.21 
    gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms: ^2.0.1 => 2.0.1 
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^2.0.10 => 2.0.11 
    gatsby-plugin-segment-js: ^2.0.1 => 2.0.1 
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^1.6.44 => 1.6.48 
    gatsby-remark-images: ^1.5.67 => 1.5.67 
    gatsby-remark-relative-images: ^0.1.2 => 0.1.2 
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^1.5.36 => 1.5.39 
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^1.7.41 => 1.7.44 
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^1.6.24 => 1.6.27 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 1.1.58
````

Through judicious debugging, I've discovered that this seems to appear when a call to setHeadComponents is added in gatsby-ssr.

Any help would be much appreciated! I literally don't even know where to look :(

Answer (score 0):

In the end, after many hours of problems, the result was a missing .babelrc in my plugin, which made webpack not know how to handle JSX.

The solution was to add babel-preset-react to my plugin's package.json, and react to my babelrc.

This worked under the plugins directory as that was handled by my website's babel config.